# Java: How can i convert a string that is returned from a database into XML

Tags: java, xml, string, object

I am trying to write a method that accesses a database and then returns a string / object in the format of XML here is the method that I have so far. I have looked at POJO and I don't believe its what i am looking for. I need to loop through and retrieve each xml child node. then display it in the correct format.

```
15  public Object getAppointment(String patientid){
16       DB db = new DB();
17       List<Object> objs = db.getData("Appointment", "patientid='"+patientid+"'");
18       Patient patient = null;
19       Phlebotomist phleb = null;
20       PSC psc = null;
21       for (Object obj : objs){
22           patient = ((Appointment)obj).getPatientid();
23           phleb = ((Appointment)obj).getPhlebid();
24           psc = ((Appointment)obj).getPscid();
25           return obj;
26       }
27       return "";
28    }
```

I need to make the obj variable in the format of XML but I cant figure it out. Here is what it returns now.

```
Appointment[id=710, Date: 2004-02-01, Time: 13:00:00
Phlebotomist: Phlebotomist[id=110, Name: Elizabeth Corday]
Patient: Patient[id=220, Name: Alice Wonderland, Address: 201 Mt. Hope Avenue, Insurance? Y, DOB: 1985-10-12
Physician: Physician[id=20, Name: Dr. Fine]]
PSC: PSC[id=510, name= Outer Banks]]
Test: AppointmentLabTest[appointmentLabTestPK=AppointmentLabTestPK[apptid=710, labtestid=86900, dxcode=292.9]
Lab Test: LabTest[id=86900, Name: Blood Group & Rh Type, whole BloodCost: 15.0]
Diagnosis: Diagnosis[code=292.9, Name: Caffeine – Related Disorder NOS]]
```

I need it to look like this when it comes back from the database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<AppointmentList>
    <appointment date="2016-12-30" id="791" time="10:00:00">
        <patient id="220">
            <name>Alice Wonderland</name>
            <address>201 Mt. Hope Avenue</address>
            <insurance>Y</insurance>
            <dob>1985-10-12</dob>
        </patient>
        <phlebotomist id="110">
            <name>Elizabeth Corday</name>
        </phlebotomist>
        <psc id="520">
            <name>Down Town</name>
        </psc>
        <allLabTests>
            <appointmentLabTest apptointmentId="791" dxcode="307.3" labTestId="86609"/>
            <appointmentLabTest apptointmentId="791" dxcode="292.9" labTestId="86900"/>
        </allLabTests>
    </appointment>
</AppointmentList>
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? I don't quite get how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

See this questions: [Binding XML using POJO and JAXB annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311374/binding-xml-using-pojo-and-jaxb-annotations).

You can create customs POJOs and annotate it with JAXB to obtain the desire output